# Excel VBA: Reformatting date to very short date with two-digit-years does not work

Tags: vba, excel, date, date-formatting

I have a list of dates exported from another application. Initially they are formatted as Standard, without any special or automatic conversion, in the format `YYYY.MM.DD`.

Previously I just replaced the dots with slashes and Excel recognized the dates as dates, automatically formatting them to the appropriate locale `DD.MM.YYYY`, which worked fine.

Now, I just wanted to remove the first two digits of the year (new format `DD.MM.YY`), but it does not work in any way I've tried. What I have done so far:

- `currentCell.Value = CDate(currentCell.Value)`: This switches the format to date, but the standard long formatting still applies.
- `currentCell.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy;@"` As seen from recording a macro and changing the value manually. Does not seem to make any difference in output format.
- `currentCell.Value = FormatDateTime(currentCell.Value, vbShortDate)`: Does not work, as Short Date is `DD.MM.YYYY`, not `DD.MM.YY` in the current locale.
- `format(date, "dd.mm.yy")` as suggested by Tom Preston and msaint: Does not change the output compared to the NumberFormat version.

Another strange thing I've observed: After applying the date change per VBA, manual change of date format via the GUI is not possible anymore/seems to not have any effect.

What could be the cause of this and how could I achieve the really short date in VBA?

Comment: try cDate(format(currentCell.Value, "dd.mm.yy"))

Comment: Can you post more of the code?  The way you reference cells in particular?

Answer (score 2):

Try 
`format(date, "dd.mm.yy")`

This will give you answer in string format if that is acceptable?
To give this some context:

```
Sub Datings()
    Dim d As Date
    d = Now
    Debug.Print d, Format(d, "dd/mm/yy")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it does not work unfortunately, still 4 digits. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the text date to something recognised by Excel as a date (replace the **.** with **/** as you did originally, then just update the numberformat in the cell.

```
Sheet1.Range("A1") = Replace(Sheet1.Range("A1"), ".", "/")
Sheet1.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy"
```

Answer (score 1):

After the suggestion to add more surrounding code by tom preston, I've tried Darren Bartrup-Cook's example code on the first cell as a very basic test. It did not work, so I used breakpoints to skip through all code before and after this piece of code.

This revealed that all the time, it *was* working correctly, but *later* other code reverted the formatting by calling `Cells(1,1).Value = "" & Cells(1,1).Value` on the correctly formatted cells. I did not notice it because in the GUI it was still shown as *Format: Date*, although internally it was overwritten.

---

The complete solution was therefore as simple as using

```
Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Replace What:=".", replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart
Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy"
```

and *not* touching column A later on.

---

So, lesson learned: use many breakpoints to narrow down the problem and check that you do not shoot yourself in the foot later on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReformatDate()
    Dim C As Range
    Dim V As Variant
    For Each C In Selection
        With C.Offset(0, 1)
            .NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy"
            If IsDate(C) Then
                .Value = C
            Else
                V = Split(C.Text, ".")
                .Value = DateSerial(V(0), V(1), V(2))
            End If
        End With
    Next C
End Sub
```

- If your system recognizes the value as a date, then just reformat
- If your system does NOT recognize the value as a date, then convert it

  - Split it using the `dot` as a delimiter
  - Convert the parts to a real date
  - write it back and format accordingly

You'll need to make appropriate modifications if you want it to overwrite, instead of putting the value in the next column; and if you want to use a more automatic method of selecting the range to convert.